# Answering How can we support you

Tags: interviewing, job-search

Nowadays many job applications ask questions as

> We are actively recruiting for a diverse and inclusive workforce so
> want to ensure we do everything we can to support your application.
> Please let us know how we can support you?

How can I tell them? Should I tell them I have ADHD? I was disqualified from a job application because I disclosed I have ADHD so opening up is sort of bad but why they such a question if they base their decision on that?

Comment: Feedback from recruiter that Manager is concerned that due to ADHD your roles are short-lived and don't think he sees u working in the company for longer so we need someone who have a good history. - Well I can't control my ADHD

Comment: Which jurisdiction? In the U.S. that manager's behavior is blatantly illegal.

Answer (score 6):

> Should I tell them I have ADHD?

No.

Unless you are looking for special accommodations (i.e. "support"), there's no need to mention that.